# How to render Material Ui buttons next to image list?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have an imagelist and I want to render buttons below the images

This is my code so far;

```
export const Media = (stuff) => {


 const { medias } = stuff;
  console.log(medias);
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <ImageList className={classes.imageList} gap={2} cols={3}>
        {medias.map((media) => (
          <ImageListItem key={media.cover_photo_url}>
            <img
              src={media.cover_photo_url}
              className={classes.image}
              style={{ borderRadius: "15px" }}
            />
            <PlayArrowIcon className={classes.overlay} />
            <ImageListItemBar subtitle={<LinkIcon></LinkIcon>} position="below"/>
          </ImageListItem>
        ))}
      </ImageList>
      {medias.map((item) => (
        <Buttons item={item} />
    ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I can display the buttons with the map function below however it doesnt scroll with the image that is relative with it horizontally

how can i make the buttons stick together with the images?
Thanks

Comment: Can you share a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) for this ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-forest-vdxgh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: ? I meant whatever you've done here, can you show this feature in a working sandbox, reproducing your current implementation

Answer (score 1):

Just Remove Second loop for buttons and bring button tag in first loop and wrapper ImageListItem and Button with a div

Replace this,

```
{medias.map((media) => (
          <ImageListItem key={media.cover_photo_url}>
            <img
              src={media.cover_photo_url}
              className={classes.image}
              style={{ borderRadius: "15px" }}
            />
            <PlayArrowIcon className={classes.overlay} />
            <ImageListItemBar subtitle={<LinkIcon></LinkIcon>} position="below"/>
          </ImageListItem>
        ))}
      </ImageList>
      {medias.map((item) => (
        <Buttons item={item} />
    ))}
```

With this,

```
{medias.map((media) => (
          <Box>
            <ImageListItem key={media.cover_photo_url}>
              <img
                src={media.cover_photo_url}
                className={classes.image}
                style={{ borderRadius: "15px" }}
              />
              <PlayArrowIcon className={classes.overlay} />
              <ImageListItemBar subtitle={<LinkIcon></LinkIcon>} position="below"/>
            </ImageListItem>
            <Buttons item={media} />
          </Box>
        ))}
```

You can Import the Box by using this

```
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
```

Comment: the media_wrapper div breaks the image list from material ui

Comment: No problem, You can change div tag to whatever you want,
just be sure to have only single fragment to return in loop.

If you don't want any tag then replace it with empty tags <></>,

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `<Box>` like this

```
      import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

      <Box>
        <ImageListItem key={media.cover_photo_url}>
          <img
            src={media.cover_photo_url}
            className={classes.image}
            style={{ borderRadius: "15px" }}
          />
          <PlayArrowIcon className={classes.overlay} />
          <ImageListItemBar subtitle={<LinkIcon></LinkIcon>} position="below"/>
        </ImageListItem>
        <Buttons item={item} />
      </Box>
```